# Can We connect multiple application with the same sqllite database

Tags: c++, reactjs, sqlite

We have two applications. One is written in React JS and other is in Visual C++. Can we access one single SQLite Database with both the application with Read/Write Access.

Comment: Yes. You can, but keep in mind that while writing to the DB, you'll have a lock that will prevent writing to it from either side of the spectrum. And you can always have multiple read from the DB.

Comment: I have had good success with WAL mode.

Comment: Thank-you everyone. Using sample application it worked.